# Release original ImageSource after a TransformedBitmap is constructed from it

Tags: c#, wpf, image, memory, bitmap

Background:

I'm building an application which will open a potentially large number of photos, generate a thumbnail to present to the user, then allow things like exif data viewing/clearing and minor post processing.
I want to allow the user to scroll through the images without pausing to load each one as it becomes visible, but I also don't want to keep dozens or hundreds of full size bitmap images in memory.

I had built a prototype of this task using `System.Drawing` using `Image` objects and their `GenerateThumbnailImage` method, but decided to move to WPF and use `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource` derived objects and the `TransformedBitmap` with a `ScaledTransform` to generate the thumbnail.

What I found, though, is that when I create a `TransformedBitmap`, it has a reference back to the source image, which is available and still present in memory. How do I release this source object?

Some relevant C# code:

```
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System;
...
private void LoadImage(){
    //Called by my class internally to handle generating the thumbnail
    //Intent is to keep only metadata and a thumbnail bitmap in memory
    Stream handle = File.OpenRead(FileName);
    BitmapDecoder source = BitmapDecoder.Create(handle,BitmapCreateOptions.None,BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
    handle.Dispose();
    //Determine a scaling ratio to force the larger of height or width to fit inside my desired thumbnail size (int)MaxDim.
    ScaleRatio = Math.Min(MaxDim/Math.Max(source.Frames[0].PixelHeight,source.Frames[0].PixelWidth),1); //a public member of the class, Double
    _ImageSource = new TransformedBitmap(source.Frames[0],new ScaleTransform(ScaleRatio,ScaleRatio)); //private member of the class, ImageSource
    _ImageSource.Freeze(); 
    _Exif = source.Frames[0].Metadata; //private member of the class, ImageMetadata
}
```

The problem here is that while I hoped that the `(BitmapDecoder)source` would be released, I can still access the object via `_ImageSource.Source`.

I have considered using `CopyPixels` or encoding the `TransformedBitmap` back into a `byte[]` stream to create a new, hopefully unattached bitmap, but both of those methods seem like unnecessary reprocessing if I can just abandon or dispose of the source or if there is some simple and fast way to create a shallow clone that I haven't discovered. My attempt at a shallow clone using `BitmapFrame.Create(TransformedBitmap)` doesn't free the memory either, but also doesn't leave me with an obvious reference.

Some testing watching memory consumption shows each image loaded costs about 30MB. An approximately 200x200@32bpp image should be about 160kB, not counting overhead.

The question again as a TL;DR: how do I release the reference to the source bitmap after a TransformedBitmap uses it?

Comment: You may use BitmapImage instead of BitmapFrame and set the DecodePixelWidth or DecodePixelHeight property. The PNG and JPEG decoders (only) will than natively decode the bitmap to the desired size. However, you should only set one of those properties to preserve aspect ratio, but can't know in advance which one fits your MaxDim. Another drawback is that BitmapImage does not support image metadata, so you would have to reload the bitmap to a BitmapFrame when you need to access its metadata.

Comment: Decoding the bitmap takes about .3 sec on my machine. I really don't want to do this twice per image to generate a BitmapFrame to access metadata and a BitmapImage to get my thumbnail.
Since posting this question, I've implemented a shallow copy using the CopyPixels method of the TransformedBitmap, and this has shrunk the footprint of each image to about 160kB as expected. It's also faster than I expected, adding only about .03 sec per image load in a simple benchmark.
I still think it's silly I have to literally copy my image pixel by pixel to break the reference.